# How to restrict a child class from overriding parent class method in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I was trying to implement template method pattern in C#. But I could not find a way to restrict child class from overriding my base class template method, unless I have a two level deep inheritance to use sealed.

If I omit virtual, child class has the liberty of providing new implementation, in which case, it will be called from child class's reference. Instead, I need some mechanism, like final in Java, wherein I can restrict the template method from overriding in the parent class.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Why would your base method even need to be `virtual`? If it's not virtual, the child class cannot override it -- it can provide a method with the same name marked as `new`, but this method will never be called if the reference has the type of the base class. And if it's not of the correct type, you can simply cast it to the base class to force this (`((Parent) child).Foo()`). If someone is explicitly calling `child.Foo()`, they know they're doing so.

Comment: Regardless of u make it virtual or non-virtual, your child class has the ability to provide new implementation. A class can't restrict what its subclasses can/should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template method should be non-virtual (it's default in C#). It should call a protected virtual/abstract method that the child classes override.

For example

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public void TemplateMethod()
    {
        //do sth
        OtherMethod();
        //do sth more
    }

    protected abstract void OtherMethod();
}

public class Child : Base
{
    protected override void OtherMethod()
    {
        //provide implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

But I have 20 child classes and the implementation of OtherMethod stays same for 9 of them. So I refrained from making it abstract. Is there a way I can reduce the number of implementations.

Comment: @RaviTiwari those 9 child classes clearly have something in common. Why not add another level of inheritance?

Comment: @RaviTiwari It seems that your classes are too big and have too many responsibilities. Try to refactor them into smaller classes and use composition to achieve the required functionality. Deep inheritance hierarchies are usually harder to understand.